# I wonder if there is something wrong with my ant junit task

Tags: ant

I'm writing my build.xml. However, it seems there is something go wrong with my junit task. when I run my junit task. I can build success, but the junit report only show that run 1 test with error. But I have more than 10 tests. So I wonder if there is something run with my junit task. Here is my code.

```
<property name="src.dir"    value="src"/>
<property name="bin.dir"    value="bin"/>
<property name="dest.dir"   value="dest"/>
<property name="test.dir"   value="test/>
<property name="lib.dir"    value="lib"/>
<path id="classpath">
    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/junit-4.11.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/ant-junit4.jar"/>
</path>

<target name="test" depends="compile">
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${bin.dir}"/>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
            </classpath>
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>   
                <batchtest fork="yes">
                    <fileset dir="${test.dir}" includes="*Test*.java"/>
                </batchtest>
            </junit>
        </target>
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong so could somebody help me out?

Comment: Maybe your JUNIT test itself...what does that code look like?

Comment: Unless all the tests are under the test directory directly, in the default package, you need `**/*Test*.java`

Answer (score 1):

And what is happening? Do you get any error messages?

You usually need to do the following:

- Compile your normal code. The resulting `*.class` files should be placed inside a directory such as `target/classes` or `build/classes`. Use the `destdir` parameter of the `<javac>` task to do this.
- Compile your JUnit tests.

  - In your **classpath**, you need all of the jars you needed to compile your ***normal*** classes
  - You need a reference to the `destdir` where your ***normal*** classes were compiled to.
  - You need the JUnit jar.
  - These should be compiled to a ***different directory*** from your normal jars. Normally, this is `target/test-classes` or `build/test-classes`.

Once you've compiled the JUnit tests, you may run them. You can use the `<junit>` task like you did.

- You need to make sure that the `includeantruntime` parameter is set to `true`
- You should also set `fork` to `true`.
- You need the same classpath (with all three elements you had) when you compiled the test classes. More jars might be needed, but usually not.
- You run the tests on the ***compiled*** JUnit test ***classfiles*** (the ones you saved to `target/test-classes` or `build/test-classes`. In your example, you're trying to run them against the source.

I use the Maven standards for my directory layout. That means my Java source is under `src/main/java` while my JUnit Java files are under `src/test/java`. Any XML or properties or other none source files needed are stored in `src/main/resources`. The regular source is compiled to `target/classes` while the Junit sources are compiled to `target/test-classes`.

This makes it easy to compile your code and test code separately without worrying about `**/test/**`, `**/Test/**`, `**/JUnit/**` exceptions in directory compiling since everything is separate.

Hope this helps.